# Passing JS object between tabs/windows on different domains

Tags: javascript

I have Express serving a page that contains a regular html table with some data. On this page I have a regular html button that when clicked runs a function that creates an object based on all of the table row data.

I am trying to determine the easiest way to pass this object to a different tab/window on a different domain.

My script is going to open a different domain site. In this domain site I want to have a chrome extension inject the pages fields with the same object data that was passed.

I am having trouble figuring out how the chrome messaging service works. I also was considering the storing the object into local storage.

What is the best approach to passing a js object from one domain to another within the same browser window?

Comment: there's `postMessage` with no support in IE reagrding your scenario and you also cannot post objects. Perhaps it works if you serialize the object to string upfront.

Comment: encode data as GET param or make an http call with credentials ( require access to target domain backend ), make jsonp call ( require access too )

Answer (score 1):

@Vanojx1 Your thinking with the GET param is excellent for my use-case.

I have solved the issue by implementing the following (FYI: example below uses jQuery).

**Web app hosted on my development box http://localhost:3000 ... This can be any domain you want since we are going to serialize the object into a GET url request**

***SERIALIZE OBJECT***

`var myObject = {
    name: 'john',
    age: '30'
}`

```
var serializedObject = jQuery.param(myObject);
window.open("https://www.whateverdomainiwant.com?" + serializedObject);
```

***DESERIALIZE OBJECT***

**I found a very nice and simple deserialize of the parameters back into the object on GitHub**
[jquery.parseparams.js](https://gist.github.com/kares/956897)